# Is there a material design pattern for two level deep content categories in a Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, material-design

I have a list of content categories: News, Sport, Entertainment etc. Categories can be two levels deep e.g Sport could have sub-categories: Baseball, Basketball etc. Both the categories and the sub-categories are tappable. The sub-categories can contain many items. It's likely that the categories will be placed in a Navigation Drawer.

Is there an off the shelf material design compatible way to do this?

I'm most concerned about the design and ux, not the implementation.

Comment: Android UI guidelines in general discourage multi-level navigation like this.  If I were coding this, I would have the categories navigate to a page, and have the navigation to the subcategories there.  Obviously it's your app and you can set it up how you want; however, the support library `NavigationView` won't do this out of the box, you'd have to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks! Have you got links to where in the guidelines it says this?

Comment: See latest Google Play Store, they have added sub items in the drawer.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski I saw that :) It's not collapsable though. It would not work with say 40 items

Comment: @krislarson Since both the categories and the subcategories are tappable, the page would have to contain both content and subcategories. Have you ever seen anything like that?

Comment: The way I handled this was to use fragment transitions in the nav drawer itself so when an item was clicked, a new menu faded in with a backbutton to the previous menu. I got the idea from the Ebay app, but my implementation was way prettier :)

Comment: @drschultz is your app on play?

Comment: I can't find the original source for staying away from more than 2 levels of nav in the drawer, but @NikolaDespotoski suggested looking at the new Google Play Store.  For instance, select Music in the nav drawer.  Now you have a secondary nav for My Music. On the Music page itself, at the top you have navs for Top Songs, Top Albums, New Releases, etc. in the material design "chip" format.  It's not three levels total, but this *is* an example of a page with both content and navigation. This is just a suggestion. Ultimately, you are the one to determine what works best for your app.

Comment: @krislarson great point!

Comment: @alexbirkett - No, unfortunately it's an internal app. But I can post the relevant code for you if you feel it would help. You can download the ebay app though to see the basic effect, although theirs doesn't use any animation or flashy transitions.

Answer (score 1):

All the `NavigationDrawer` contains is a `RecyclerView` which is attached to an `Adapter` so you can achieve this the same way as you would with a general `RecyclerView` and it will behave in the same way.

It will generally consist of keeping note of which category is open and which is closed and building your `Adapter` around that logic, if a certain category is open your list will grow by that categories sub-category count etc.

**Examples of implementation from Now TV Sky app:**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm most concerned about how it looks not the implementation details. Will update the question.

Comment: It won't look bad. You can see an example of what you want to achieve by downloading the free NowTV app from Google Play and looking at their navigation drawer which sports three collapsible categories.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but if it's [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pccw.nowtvapp) it's not material design.

Comment: No it's this one - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bskyb.nowtv.beta

Comment: It says "This app is incompatible with all of your devices." Maybe because I'm not in the UK?

Comment: I guess so, would you like me to upload some screenshots for you? It's quite nice.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks

Comment: Looks like you might be able to get the raw APK from here - https://appraw.com/apk/now-tv-apk-download-1dj14

Comment: Uploaded the screenshots above.